# Difference between arrows in functions

Tags: functions

I'd like you to explain to me the difference between the two arrows in functions
$\to$ and $\mapsto$
I know we use the first one to link the domain E and the range F while we use the second one to link the argument and the function. But I don't know why we can't just mix between them. Are there any reasons ?
Thank you in advance for your answers
Regards

Comment: we can't mix between them because they describe different things.

Answer (score 1):

We write $f:E\to F$ to denote that $f$ is a function with domain $E$ and range $F$, and we can write the rule for $f$ as $f\mapsto f(x)$.  For example, we might define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $x\mapsto 2x+1$.  It's just the convention, and it's useful to know, without needing any other context, that $\to$ is at the level of "types" and $\mapsto$ is at the level of "values."  Syntactically, in $x\mapsto E$ the left-hand side introduces a new variable $x$ that can be referenced in the expression $E$.  The $\to$ arrow does not introduce new variables like this, so it's a fundamentally different sort of thing.

(Something that can be useful with the $\mapsto$ notation is defining functions with types like $\mathbb{R}\to(\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})$ with a rule like $x\mapsto(y\mapsto 2x+3y)$.  This is a function that takes a real number and produces a function from the real numbers to the real numbers.  A more complicated, but useful, example like this is the linear isomorphism that sends a vector space to its double dual, which might be written as $V\to ((V\to\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R})$ with the rule $v\mapsto (f\mapsto f(v))$.)